# jQuery's .add on an empty set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am working on a plugin with quite a few options and as a consequence I am trying to keep track of a set of elements and put them in a variable. The variable cannot be empty (but that is of no concern here). Let's say there are only two options, then the variable will hold one or two elements as a jQuery object, i.e. `$("#el1, #el2")`. I tried the following, but the result of adding is still `$([])`.

```
var track = $([]);
someFunc() {
    if (option1) track.add("#el1");
    if (option2) track.add("#el2");
}

// result is `$([])`
```

Note that I don't want an array back, but a jQuery selector as I posted in the example above.

Comment: nice jquery object of a empty array:))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first sort out which elements/selectors you need.
And then use these to init the `track` variable with an jQuery object passing in all the relevant selectors.

```
var track = someFunc();

// you would have to check the length of `track` first as it may be only an empty array (length == 0) and no real jQuery object
if (track.length) {
    //...
}

// returns a jQuery object with all the matched elements
// or an empty array if there is no relevant selector
function someFunc() {
    // place to store the selectors
    var selectors = [];

    // store the relevant selectors in <selectors>
    if (option1) selectors.push("#el1");
    if (option2) selectors.push("#el2");

    // if there is at least one selector in <selectors>
    if (selectors.length > 0) {
        // create a jQuery object of them and return it
        return $(selectors.join())
    } else {
        // otherwise we return an empty array
        // this allows us to use .length in both cases
        return [];
    }

    // or always return a jQuery object
    // return $(selectors.join());
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are doing? Also, I would assume it should be `selectors.join(,)`?

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer is currently flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed.

Comment: @BramVanroy I've added some comments

Answer (score 0):

Use a array join on coma:

```
var elements = [];

elements.push('#one');

console.log(elements.join(','));
$(elements.join(','));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8xx8x1xe/

Comment: Not what I want, I want to combine selectors. Please re-read my post and take a look at the example.